# JAVA DEPLOY - FAIL - Application already exists at path /MiProyecto

Tags: javascript, java, jsf, tomcat

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto en Java ICEfaces, cuando trato de hacer deploy me da el siguiente error:

```
OK - Undeployed application at context path /MiProyecto
In-place deployment at C:\MiProyecto\MiProyecto\build\web
deploy?config=file:/C:/Users/JULIAN~1.COR/AppData/Local/Temp/3/context48767.xml&path=/MiProyecto
FAIL - Application already exists at path /MiProyecto
C:\MiProyecto\MiProyecto\nbproject\build-impl.xml:594: The module has not been deployed.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 9 seconds)
```

Esto no me deja correr la aplicación.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes tener alguna otra aplicación corriendo bajo la misma ruta de la que intentas desplegar.

[Documentación oficial de Apache Tomcat](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/html-manager-howto.html#Deploy_Message):

> Application already exists at path /foo
>   The context paths for all currently running web applications must be unique. Therefore, you must either undeploy the existing web application using this context path, or choose a different context path for the new one.